# Linux Export command syntax

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, path

What is the difference between these two command lines?

```
export PATH=/usr/local/something/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/something/bin/
```

Using Ubuntu 16.04 command shell.

Comment: One prepends a value to `$PATH` and the other appends a value.

Answer (score 2):

Like larsks said, the difference is based on whether the executable you are adding a PATH to is matched/found first or after the existing PATH you have is exhausted. It will matter if you have two executables named the same thing, or for speed.

Comment: What is exactly the function of the curly brackets?

Comment: not exactly sure I know, my guess is that it is some form of interpolation for the existing variable. when you execute the line it only effects the shell you are in right then,  i would try it and see what happens to your PATH, you can just do execute bash (type bash) to get back to where you were.